# Get Image From PHP using Cocoa-Touch

Tags: php, cocoa-touch

I got this php code.. that creates a pie Chart
when you go to the site: `http://localhost/social/Test.php?data=100*200*100`

How do i get this image from the php file to my Xcode project?
When you enter the site the image will download
But when you enter the site on the iPhone the image will only show

```
<?php
$show_label = true; // true = show label, false = don't show label.
$show_percent = true; // true = show percentage, false = don't show percentage.
$show_text = true; // true = show text, false = don't show text.
$show_parts = false; // true = show parts, false = don't show parts.
$label_form = 'square'; // 'square' or 'round' label.
$width = 199;
$background_color = 'FFFFFF'; // background-color of the chart...
$text_color = '000000'; // text-color.
$colors = array('003366', 'CCD6E0', '7F99B2','F7EFC6', 'C6BE8C', 'CC6600','990000','520000','BFBFC1','808080'); // colors of the slices.
$shadow_height = 16; // Height on shadown.
$shadow_dark = true; // true = darker shadow, false = lighter shadow...

// DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE...

$data = $_GET["data"];
$label = $_GET["label"];

$height = $width/2;
$data = explode('*',$data);

if ($label != '') $label = explode('*',$label);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($label); $i++) 
{
    if ($data[$i]/array_sum($data) < 0.1) $number[$i] = ' '.number_format(($data[$i]/array_sum($data))*100,1,',','.').'%';
    else $number[$i] = number_format(($data[$i]/array_sum($data))*100,1,',','.').'%';
    if (strlen($label[$i]) > $text_length) $text_length = strlen($label[$i]);
}

if (is_array($label))
{
    $antal_label = count($label);
    $xtra = (5+15*$antal_label)-($height+ceil($shadow_height));
    if ($xtra > 0) $xtra_height = (5+15*$antal_label)-($height+ceil($shadow_height));

    $xtra_width = 5;
    if ($show_label) $xtra_width += 20;
    if ($show_percent) $xtra_width += 45;
    if ($show_text) $xtra_width += $text_length*8;
    if ($show_parts) $xtra_width += 35;
}

$img = ImageCreateTrueColor($width+$xtra_width, $height+ceil($shadow_height)+$xtra_height);

ImageFill($img, 0, 0, colorHex($img, $background_color));

foreach ($colors as $colorkode) 
{
    $fill_color[] = colorHex($img, $colorkode);
    $shadow_color[] = colorHexshadow($img, $colorkode, $shadow_dark);
}

$label_place = 5;

if (is_array($label))
{
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($label); $i++) 
    {
        if ($label_form == 'round' && $show_label  && $data[$i] > 0)
        {
            imagefilledellipse($img,$width+11,$label_place+5,10,10,colorHex($img, $colors[$i % count($colors)]));
            imageellipse($img,$width+11,$label_place+5,10,10,colorHex($img, $text_color));
        }
        else if ($label_form == 'square' && $show_label && $data[$i] > 0)
        {   
            imagefilledrectangle($img,$width+6,$label_place,$width+16,$label_place+10,colorHex($img, $colors[$i % count($colors)]));
            imagerectangle($img,$width+6,$label_place,$width+16,$label_place+10,colorHex($img, $text_color));
        }

        if ($data[$i] > 0)
        {
            if ($show_percent) $label_output = $number[$i].' ';
            if ($show_text) $label_output = $label_output.$label[$i].' ';
            if ($show_parts) $label_output = $label_output.$data[$i];

            imagestring($img,'2',$width+20,$label_place,$label_output,colorHex($img, $text_color));
            $label_output = '';

            $label_place = $label_place + 15;
        }
    }
}
$centerX = round($width/2);
$centerY = round($height/2);
$diameterX = $width-4;
$diameterY = $height-4;

$data_sum = array_sum($data);

$start = 270;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) 
{
    $value += $data[$i];
    $end = ceil(($value/$data_sum)*360) + 270;
    $slice[] = array($start, $end, $shadow_color[$value_counter % count($shadow_color)], $fill_color[$value_counter % count($fill_color)]);
    $start = $end;
    $value_counter++;
}

for ($i=$centerY+$shadow_height; $i>$centerY; $i--) 
{
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($slice); $j++)
    {
        if ($slice[$j][0] != $slice[$j][1]) ImageFilledArc($img, $centerX, $i, $diameterX, $diameterY, $slice[$j][0], $slice[$j][1], $slice[$j][2], IMG_ARC_PIE);
    }
}   

for ($j = 0; $j < count($slice); $j++)
{
    if ($slice[$j][0] != $slice[$j][1]) ImageFilledArc($img, $centerX, $centerY, $diameterX, $diameterY, $slice[$j][0], $slice[$j][1], $slice[$j][3], IMG_ARC_PIE);
}

OutputImage($img);
ImageDestroy($img);


function colorHex($img, $HexColorString) 
{
    $R = hexdec(substr($HexColorString, 0, 2));
    $G = hexdec(substr($HexColorString, 2, 2));
    $B = hexdec(substr($HexColorString, 4, 2));
    return ImageColorAllocate($img, $R, $G, $B);
}

function colorHexshadow($img, $HexColorString, $mork) 
{
    $R = hexdec(substr($HexColorString, 0, 2));
    $G = hexdec(substr($HexColorString, 2, 2));
    $B = hexdec(substr($HexColorString, 4, 2));

    if ($mork)
    {
        ($R > 99) ? $R -= 100 : $R = 0;
        ($G > 99) ? $G -= 100 : $G = 0;
        ($B > 99) ? $B -= 100 : $B = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ($R < 220) ? $R += 35 : $R = 255;
        ($G < 220) ? $G += 35 : $G = 255;
        ($B < 220) ? $B += 35 : $B = 255;               
    }           

    return ImageColorAllocate($img, $R, $G, $B);
}

function OutputImage($img) 
{
    header('Content-type: image/jpg');
    ImageJPEG($img,NULL,100);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

please do a post request form php server to your app, convert the image to base64 encoding and pass this as a string, then save this file as .jpg or .png etc as required.

Thanks 
djrecker

Comment: No base64 conversion is needed. Just grab `NSData` with `dataWithContentsOfUrl`, and then get `UIImage` via `imageWithData`.

Comment: And, incidentally, given that this php is generating a jpg, you'd probably have to use that, unless you manually convert it to a png at some point.

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the image data via `dataWithContentsOfUrl` and then either

1. Use `imageWithData` to get your `UIImage`; or
2. Write the `NSData` to a file with `writeToFile` and then you can later retrieve the image via `imageWithContentsOfFile`

Note, you'll have to put that PHP code on a web server accessible by the iPhone (as obviously `localhost` won't work). So, it might look like (I've replaced your `localhost` reference with `host.com` ... you'll have to replace that with the URL of the web site you put your PHP code on):

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://host.com/social/Test.php?data=100*200*100";
NSURL    *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSError  *err;

NSData   *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url options:0 error:&err];
NSAssert(imageData, @"Unable to retrieve image");
```

Now you can use that image:

```
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Or, alternatively, now you can write it to a file on your iPhone, too, if you want:

```
NSString *documentsFolder  = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentFullPath = [documentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"pie.jpg"]; // I noticed from the php source that this is a jpg

BOOL success = [imageData writeToFile:documentFullPath options:0 error:&err];
NSAssert(success, @"Unable to write file");
```

Which you can retrieve later:

```
self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:documentFullPath];
```

Note, this is an inefficient way to draw a pie chart in iOS (to have php server generate jpg that you then download, requiring Internet connection and download at 3G speeds if you're not on wifi, etc.). I'd probably do something with Core Graphics or grab one of the various charting/graphing APIs out there. If you google "[ios 3d pie chart](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=ios+3d+pie+chart&oq=ios+3d+pie+chart)" you'll get a bunch of hits. [This one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7321/3D-Pie-Chart) looks pretty cool, though I've never tried it.